# How to fill any cell which contains only spaces with np.nan?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

It is required to have a method that firstly checks the content of each cell of a dataframe and if the cell contains only spaces and nothing else then fills it with `np.nan`. To do so, I have written the following method:

```
def white_space_replacer(df):
    for i in list(df):
        if not is_numeric_dtype(df[i]) and df[i].any().isspace():
            df[i] = df[i].fillna(np.nan)
```

But it doesn't change anything.

What should be changed in the method to work properly?

Comment: post data not links. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code to fill in the empty spaces with NaN directly while reading a `.csv` file using pandas.

```
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv', skipinitialspace=True)
```